# How to efficiently enumerate binary black-white trees, while accounting for symmetry?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, enumeration

Consider the following type of black-white binary trees:

```hs
data BW = Black BW BW | White BW BW | Leaf Nat
```

With the following equivalence relation:

```
∀ a b c d . Black (White a b) (White c d) == White (Black a c) (Black b d)
```

So, for example, `Black (White 0 1) (White 2 3)` and `White (Black 0 2) (Black 1 3)` are equivalent. I'm interested in enumerating all unique trees of given size (where the size of a tree is just the count of constructors) as efficiently as possible. A brute-force approach would involve just enumerating all trees of given depth, and filtering out equivalent trees. This would be very inefficient for two reasons:

1. It would wastefully generate / consider a huge number of equivalent trees
2. Filtering would be quadratic, as it would require comparing with all former trees

Is there an efficient algorithm to generate all BW trees of given depth, without generating identical trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for numberless trees, that should easily adapt to your problem.

```
data BW = Black BW BW | White BW BW | Leaf deriving Show

notBlack :: BW -> Bool
notBlack (Black _ _ ) = False
notBlack _ = True

-- generate BW trees in which no White node has two Black children
gen :: Int -> [BW]
gen 1 = [Leaf]
gen n = do
  n1 <- [1..n-2]
  t1 <- gen n1
  let n2 = n-1-n1
  t2 <- gen n2
  Black t1 t2 : [White t1 t2 | notBlack t1 || notBlack t2]

main = mapM_ print (gen 7)
```

While it's possible to enforce the constraint in the type system, the result is rather more cumbersome:

```
data BlackT = Black T T deriving Show
data NotBlackT = WW NotBlackT NotBlackT | WB NotBlackT BlackT | BW BlackT NotBlackT | Leaf deriving Show
data T = B BlackT | NB NotBlackT deriving Show

genB :: Int -> [BlackT]
genB n = [Black t1 t2 | n1 <- [1..n-2], t1 <- gen n1, t2 <- gen (n-1-n1)]

genNB :: Int -> [NotBlackT]
genNB 1 = [Leaf]
genNB n = [WW t1 t2 | n1 <- [1..n-2], t1 <- genNB n1, t2 <- genNB (n-1-n1)]
       ++ [WB t1 t2 | n1 <- [1..n-2], t1 <- genNB n1, t2 <- genB  (n-1-n1)]
       ++ [BW t1 t2 | n1 <- [1..n-2], t1 <- genB  n1, t2 <- genNB (n-1-n1)]

gen :: Int -> [T]
gen n = map B (genB n) ++ map NB (genNB n)

main = mapM_ print (gen 7)
```

Answer (score 6):

Given any BW tree, you can systematically transform it into an equivalent tree that contains no `White` nodes with two `Black` children, working recursively from the root.

Furthermore, the resulting "Black-biased" tree will be the same size as the original tree, and no two such Black-biased trees will be equivalent unless they are exactly the same.

Black-biased trees can therefore be used as a canonical form, and you can just enumerate the Black-biased trees of a given size:

```
data BT = Black BBT BBT | BTLeaf Nat
data WT = WhiteWW WT WT | WhiteWB WT BT | WhiteBW BT WT | WTLeaf Nat
data BBT = BT BT | WT WT
```

Comment: The definition of `White` looks wrong here: you can't have three constructors with the same name.

Comment: ...and `BBT` probably needs fields for each of its constructors.

Comment: It seems I don't know how to write this in Haskell.  I was guessing from the example, and expecting | to be a simple type union.  Since the OP indicated that he was measuring size by the # of constructors, I was being careful to keep the same number.